# What is purpose of NULL at the end of this loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Revising an old program.  It issues `NULL;` and the end of this loop.

Why?  What is it supposed to do?  Nothing as far as I can tell.

Here is the loop:

```
--Price Break Loop
OPEN c_price_breaks;
<<c_price_breaks_loop>>
l_prc_brk_count := 1;
LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line('Price break loop..');
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.log,'Price break loop..');

    --FOR prc_brk_cnt IN 1..L_prc_brk_count LOOP 
    FETCH c_price_breaks INTO l_price_override, l_ship_to_organization_id_pb, l_ship_to_organization_code_pb, l_ship_to_location_id_pb, l_ship_to_location_code_pb, l_quantity;
    EXIT WHEN c_price_breaks%NOTFOUND;

    --Inserting into line location interface table
    INSERT INTO PO.PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_INTERFACE (
        INTERFACE_LINE_LOCATION_ID,
        INTERFACE_HEADER_ID,
        INTERFACE_LINE_ID,              
        SHIPMENT_TYPE,
        SHIPMENT_NUM,
        SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION_ID,               
        SHIP_TO_LOCATION_ID,                 
        QUANTITY,       
        UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
        PRICE_OVERRIDE,
        CREATION_DATE
    ) VALUES (
        po_line_locations_interface_s.nextval,  --INTERFACE_LINE_LOCATION_ID,
        po_headers_interface_s.currval,         --INTERFACE_HEADER_ID,
        po_lines_interface_s.currval,           --INTERFACE_LINE_ID,             
        'QUOTATION',                            --SHIPMENT_TYPE,
        l_prc_brk_count,                        --SHIPMENT_NUM,
        l_ship_to_organization_id_pb,           --SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION_ID,               
        l_ship_to_location_id_pb,               --SHIP_TO_LOCATION_ID,   
        l_quantity,                             --QUANTITY,     
        l_unit_of_measure,                      --UOM
        l_price_override,                       --PRICE_OVERRIDE
        SYSDATE                                 --CREATION_DATE,
    );    

    l_prc_brk_count := l_prc_brk_count+1;

    <<END_of_c_price_breaks_loop>>

    NULL;

END LOOP; --END of Price break loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `NULL` is required while you have a label at the end of the PL/SQL block formed by the `LOOP`.

The Oracle documentation for the [`GOTO` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/goto_statement.htm) states:

> GOTO Statement
>
> The GOTO statement branches unconditionally to a statement label or block label. The label must be unique within its scope and must precede an executable statement or a PL/SQL block. The GOTO statement transfers control to the labelled statement or block.

The `<<END_of_c_price_breaks_loop>>` is a label and it must precede an executable statement or a PL/SQL block; `NULL;` is such a statement.

```sql
DECLARE
  l_prc_brk_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  <<c_price_breaks_loop>>
  l_prc_brk_count := 1;
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Price break loop..');
    EXIT WHEN l_prc_brk_count > 3;

    l_prc_brk_count := l_prc_brk_count+1;

    <<END_of_c_price_breaks_loop>>

    NULL;

  END LOOP; --END of Price break loop
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> ```

Removing the `NULL;`

```sql
DECLARE
  l_prc_brk_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  <<c_price_breaks_loop>>
  l_prc_brk_count := 1;
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Price break loop..');
    EXIT WHEN l_prc_brk_count > 3;

    l_prc_brk_count := l_prc_brk_count+1;

    <<END_of_c_price_breaks_loop>>
  END LOOP; --END of Price break loop
END;
/
```

Gives:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 3:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null raise
>    return select update while with <an identifier>
>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
>    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
> ```

Removing the label:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_prc_brk_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  <<c_price_breaks_loop>>
  l_prc_brk_count := 1;
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Price break loop..');
    EXIT WHEN l_prc_brk_count > 3;

    l_prc_brk_count := l_prc_brk_count+1;
  END LOOP; --END of Price break loop
END;
/
```

Gives:

> ```
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> Price break loop..
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be9f1c66efc60c6c021c4a28b955c350)*

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds

Comment: Thanks.  This SP has no GOTO, so its clear the original developer was confused about proper cursor loops

Comment: @alexherm Labels also work with `EXIT` statements so if you have an inner and an outer `LOOP` then you can label the outer loop and break out of both of them simultaneously using `EXIT outer_label WHEN ....`. So its not just `GOTO` statements you need to look for (that's just where I happened to find the appropriate documentation for the required program structure after a label). However, that should not affect the removal of a label at the end of a block.

Answer (score 2):

The `null` is there because there has to be a statement after a label.  If you try to run this block, for example

```
declare
  l_cnt integer := 0;
begin
  loop
    exit when l_cnt > 1;
    l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
    <<foo>>
  end loop;
end;
```

you'll get a syntax error because the label `foo` doesn't have an executable statement after it.  If you add a `null;`, the block compiles

```
declare
  l_cnt integer := 0;
begin
  loop
    exit when l_cnt > 1;
    l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
    <<foo>>
    null;
  end loop;
end;
```

Now, it doesn't appear that either of the labels in the code you posted are actually doing anything useful themselves (other than maybe functioning as comments?).  Unless you have code somewhere else that has a `goto` one of these labels, you could eliminate both the `c_price_breaks_loop` label and the `END_of_c_price_breaks_loop` label and then you can get rid of the `null;` statement.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Same comment I wrote to MT0.